# Dropped out from my first year college and then took admission next year in bsc it. Now in last year what should I explain to the recruiters?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, employment-gaps

After my 12th I took admission for BSC course. I passed the first semester but I got failed in 2 subjects and didn't gave one exam because I was never interested in the stream. Then in the next year I again took admission in other college for Bsc.It course.

I submitted a affidavit there that I had an educational gap due to financial reasons. They accepted it. Now I am in last year and have good grades in all semesters. I have applied for off campus recruitments. So when the interviewer ask me about my gap what should I tell him?

Is the gap because of financial reason or because I dropped out from first year(I am confused about this because I told my college that it was a financial gap also I don't have my semester marksheet for the 1yr course).

What should I answer?

Comment: I'm confused. Was the primary reason for the gap financial or academic?

Comment: I took admission in first year for plain bsc course after my 12th exam. but in the 2nd semester i didnt gave one exam. so I got a drop. Then in the next year I  took admission in another college for bsc IT. I didnot tell them that I had been in another college I just submitted that due to my financial problems I took a gap. and got admission for bsc IT course in first year

Comment: primary reason was academics.

Comment: So you went to one college, and dropped out.  Then the next year you enrolled to another college and did well.  There is no actual "gap"?  Just tell them the truth then, that you did a year at one college, dropped out then completed your degree elsewhere.  The fact that you subsequently qualified overrides the earlier flunking out.

Comment: Will they ask for any marksheets or proof from the year which I had dropped out?

Comment: Also, you don't have to bring up the first college. Just say you graduated from College B and don't even list the first.

Answer (score 2):

"Someone took 5 years to finish college" and "someone took a year off before graduating college" are not red flags in any environment I've seen. They're actually pretty common. In fact, [most students don't earn a degree in four years](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/02/education/most-college-students-dont-earn-degree-in-4-years-study-finds.html?_r=0).

If a recruiter asks, a polite (and truthful answer) might be, "I tried another degree program/university and it didn't work out." This does eventually lead you open to "why didn't it work out", but most recruiters (and certainly no managers I've met) will press that much further.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience of more than 10 years as a software professional; where I have hired everyone from seasoned veterans (several years senior to me) to fresh graduates out of high school and college; I can tell you that transcripts do not matter in the software world.

If you were applying to a recruiter for a graduate school or further education (like a ph.d program or similar) then yes your transcript would be scrutinized.

Otherwise, just tell the recruiter when do you expect to graduate and any practical projects you may have done or expect to complete. The other details are sundry.

Recruiters don't look at nor care about your transcript. They may care about your final GPA but that's about it.

This is because most recruiters and many HR professional are well aware of the curricula that is offered at higher education (it is their business to know where to hire good students for a particular job role - so they don't prefer computer science graduates from a college that is known for their arts program, etc.) and more practically - colleges and universities often liaise with businesses in the area to ensure that their graduates are employable in the market.

In short, the recruiter will know more about your course plan that you probably suspect (in some cases, if this is a university sponsored event - the recruiter may even be an alumnus).

So, don't worry so much about your transcript.

Comment: thanks everyone. I have been filling forms of TCS, Infosys etc recently. In that we have to mention any gap in education and reason for that. Also the college campus don't consider students with a gap. So I was in dilemma what exactly should I tell if the recruiter asks me.